# middleman console: how to use it?

Tags: middleman

I would like to know how to use `middleman console`. Is it a simple irb? What can I do with it that differs from the simple irb?

```
middleman console [options]         # Start an interactive console in the cont...
```

I have some articles and I try to do `Article.all` but I had this following error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Middleman::Application::MiddlemanApplication1::Article
    from (irb#1):1
```

and I also have [local-data](http://middlemanapp.com/advanced/local-data/) `/data/friends.json` but Friend.all output error too.

```
{
  "friends": [
    "Tom",
    "Dick",
    "Harry"
  ]
}
```

I saw that `Symbol.all_symbols` output a lots of middleman variable and functions but  I don't really know how to use the middleman console.

Comment: I like to [use Pry to discover the answer](https://andrew.kvalhe.im/use-pry-as-the-middleman-console/) to this sort of thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oh man, I just spend a few hours trying to solve something that would have gone a lot faster if I had known that there was a middleman console!

I was trying to build the next/back logic for going through articles on my blog.  There's a chronological thing, but I wanted to also be able to go back and forth on tags.  There are a few that are tagged both "ruby" and (say) "rails", and "the next" for both tags was the same I wanted to list it together under both the tags.

The main problem was that I didn't know what sorts of things were available to me in the templates file.  When you startup `middleman console` it loads up the configuration of your site so then you can start poking around.

```
$ bundle exec irb
2.0.0-p481 :001 > blog
NameError: undefined local variable or method `blog' for main:Object
from (irb):1
2.0.0-p481 :002 > exit
$ middleman console
== LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect
2.0.0-p481 :001 > blog
=> #<Middleman::Blog::BlogData: [#<Middleman::Blog::BlogArticle: {"title"=>"Emb
```

*etc.*

What middleman console does is load up the middleman environment, and then lets you call methods on the current `Middleman::Application` object.  If you are using a middleman extension and they've defined helpers, you can get to them here and start poking around.

Handy things:

`config` is the middleman config object.

`data` is the middleman data object, from the data directory

`blog` is the blog config, if you are using middleman-blog

`drafts` are the draft articles, if you are using middleman-blog-drafts

Comment: Finally... an answer! Thank you very much. I would like to know what is the link that you find all the information about ['config','data','blog','drafts'] I was looking at [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/Cli/Console) and I couldn't find information about those objects. I was thinking like in rails and tryied to do `Articles.all` in fact as you point out I should have tryied `blog.articles`

Comment: My process was like thisL:  (I guess I can't use new lines here!) Start up `middleman console` and type in a random method.  You get an error: `undefined local variable or method `this_is_not_a_method' for #<Middleman::Application:0x70328389148900>` which implies that's where you are running.  `self.class` returns `Middleman::Application::MiddlemanApplication1` so you are in that context.  Basically this means that all helper methods are available to you in the console.  `sitemap` will return the middleman sitemap for example.

Comment: When I try to use middleman functions (defined inside the 'helpers' section) it tells me `NoMethodError: undefined method `tags_to_mi' for #<Middleman::Application:0x50527180>`. Any idea why I can't access the functions? [This thread is what I want, but the answer does not work for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144577/how-can-helpers-be-accessed-from-middleman-console)