# How can helpers be accessed from Middleman Console

Tags: middleman, middleman-4

How can helpers be accessed from `middleman console`? Answer for both 3.x and 4.x would be helpful if it's not the same object path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any documentation on this, so settled for the following work around:

Here's my helper

```
module PageHelpers
  def thing
    "THING!"
  end
end
```

Call the helper method on an instance of a class that includes it:

```sh
$ bundle exec middleman console
irb...> (class Thing; include PageHelpers; end).new.thing
=> "THING!"
```